# MongoDB "Invalid BSON Field Name"

Tags: java, mongodb

I know that there's probably a better way to do this however I'm completely stumped. I'm writing a Discord bot in which a user is able to add points to other users, however I can't figure out how to replace a user's "points". My code is as follows:

```
BasicDBObject cursor = new BasicDBObject();
        cursor.put(user.getAsMember().getId(), getMongoPoints(user.getAsMember()));
        if(cursor.containsKey(user.getAsMember().getId())) {
            Document old = new Document(user.getAsMember().getId(), getMongoPoints(user.getAsMember()));
            Document doc = new Document(user.getAsMember().getId(), getMongoPoints(user.getAsMember()) + Integer.parseInt(amount.getAsString()));
            collection.findOneAndUpdate(old, doc);
        }
```

My getMongoPoints function:

```
 public static int getMongoPoints(Member m) {
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("database");
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .build();
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("SRU");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("points");
    DistinctIterable<Integer> docs = collection.distinct(m.getId(), Integer.class);
    MongoCursor<Integer> result = docs.iterator();
    return result.next();
}
```

I've tried findOneAndReplace, however that simply makes a new entry without deleting the old one. The error I receive is: `Invalid BSON field name 262014495440896000`

Everything else works, include writing to the database itself which is why I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologize if this is written poorly.

Comment: What version of the Java driver are you using?  Is `user` an entity class (a POJO)?  Did you intend for the user's ID to be the field name?

Comment: Java 11, user is an entity, and yes I am intending for it to be used as the field name
@Paul

Comment: What are the actual contents of `old` and `doc`?

Comment: @Joe the actual contents of ```old``` are ```262014495440896000:100``` and the actual contents of new are the same as old however a new argument, for the sake of simplicity we'll say that new will be adding 50 to 100.

Comment: I was asking what version of the MongoDB Java driver you're using but it doesn't matter given your design decision to use ID as the field name.  Why use ID as the field name instead of as the value of a field?  That's a bad choice for several reasons such as you can't create indices for a field whose name is different in every document and updates will be infinitely harder.  Also since `user` is an entity it is better work work with an instance of the class rather than as a `Document`, so  `MongoCollection<UserEntity> collection = database.getCollection("points", UserEntity.class);`

Comment: @Paul my bad, but I'm using the latest MongoDB Java driver. My decision to use the ID as the field name was because it's the only unique substance that the API I'm using offers. I can't use any other as they're subject to change.

Comment: If you are persisting your own entity then I would make a field `memberId` and give it the value of `getAsMember().getId()`.  Create an index on `memberId`  and you'll be able to use the [update $inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator.  In fact all your CRUD operations will be easy peasy!  Right now you're wrestling with a problem you shouldn't have in the first place.

Comment: @Paul is there any specific way to define the index as an object?

Comment: Another problem with this is the fetch-mutate-save model will be subject to race conditions if there are ever 2 updates to the same user.

Answer (score 0):

BSON field names must be string.  From the spec:

> Zero or more modified UTF-8 encoded characters followed by '\x00'. The (byte*) MUST NOT contain '\x00', hence it is not full UTF-8.

To use `262014495440896000` as a field name, convert it to string first.

Comment: I've tried to make the field name  string, and it doesn't accept it. For example, I tested "test" as the entry and it returned with ```Invalid BSON field name test```, which is why I'm so confused.